# How to trace the sql queries that my windows app generates?

Tags: sql, client-side, trace

I want to do sql client-side tracing to see the scope of databases and queries that my local Windows application is generating.

Everyone on the Web talks about server-side tracing but my app talks to at least five different servers, so that's pretty hard to do effectively.

Any recommendations?

Comment: How are your queries generated on the client side? How is your application built? The answer will differ wildly based on this.. I often generate the queries manually, and troubleshooting is often done by just printing it somewhere before executing it.. If you're letting a framework or utility manage all of your SQL activity, you may have no choice but to profile it on the server side (or use SQL Profiler on the client side if using SQL Server.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Data access layer, or a limited # of functions that actually execute the sql, you could build in a logging mechanism that you could enable/disable for debugging purposes.  Sorry if that's a generic answer.

Comment: Because you are hitting multiple database servers, I think logging is the only answer.